# как реализовать механику из игры supertype на unity?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Хотел сделать 2D игру по типу SuperType. Основная механика в ней заключается в том, что игрок вводит текст, и буквы этого текста становятся физическими объектами, которые падают и взаимодействуют с окружением. Но как это реализовать?